# tiger192,4 php hash generating different values in different php versions

Tags: php, hash

Does anyone else had that issue?

In a php 5.4.9-4  environment when I call `echo hash('tiger192,4','test');` I receive `14b5375c7b29cbf5f9e70a199a40e59dd4d5f1df218b5249` as response.

Now, in a php 5.3.10 environment when I call the SAME function I receive `f5cb297b5c37b5149de5409a190ae7f949528b21dff1d5d4`

I think is something with the tiger192 hash family because when using sha256, for example, it generates the same value.

I saw that in php 5.4 the tiger family is using big-endian byte ordering. Now, does anyone knows how to disable it to keep the compatibility?

Answer (score 0):

Sadly there is no a compatibility setting for this, and you should not expect to be able to move between major versions of software without having to rework parts of your code.

If resetting the hashed data is not an option (but then i don't see why not? As inconvenient it may be, after that your hashes will be much more secure) then you could write your own function to do the hashing since algorithm is publicly available http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tiger_(cryptography)#Algorithm.